# Appcelerator custom module receiving callback for onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to create a custom module in Appcelerator for the new Square API for Android. I have everything the way I want it, but the main problem is that I want to be able to notify the caller that the payment was successful for if it failed. The Square API says this:

> After Square finishes, Android invokes Activity.onActivityResult() on the activity passed to the constructor. The request code passed to this method will be passed to onActivityResult(). The result code is Activity.RESULT_CANCELED if the payment was canceled or Activity.RESULT_OK if the payment succeeded.

I've been passing the TiContext.currentActivity to the constructor:

```
public SquareModule(TiContext tiContext) {
    super(tiContext);

    ourSquare = new Square(tiContext.getActivity());
}
```

And then in the method that actually runs the payment, I have this that basically tries to set the passed in callback to the onResult handlers of the current activity using the registerResultHandler in the TiActivitySupportHelper class.

```
    public void runPayment(KrollInvocation invocation, int price, String description, KrollCallback handler) {
        Log.i(LCAT, "runPayment called");

        // Register the passed in function as a handler on the onResult stack

        this.resultCallback = handler;
        Activity activity = invocation.getTiContext().getActivity();
        TiActivitySupportHelper support = new TiActivitySupportHelper(activity);
        int code = support.getUniqueResultCode();
        support.registerResultHandler(code, this);

                // Some of the payment work here

        ourSquare.squareUp(Bill.containing(advice), code);
    }
```

The main module class implements TiActivityResultHandler and implements onResult and onError. These methods are not being called at all. And of course the passed in method isn't being called either.

For completeness, see the implementation of the onResult and onError handlers:

```
@Override
public void onResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.i(LCAT, "onResult Called");
    if (resultCallback == null) return;
    KrollDict event = new KrollDict();
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_RESULT_CODE, resultCode);
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_INTENT, new IntentProxy(getTiContext(), data));
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE, this);
    resultCallback.callAsync(event);
}

@Override
public void onError(Activity activity, int requestCode, Exception e)
{
    Log.i(LCAT, "onError Called");
    if (resultCallback == null) return;
    KrollDict event = new KrollDict();
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    event.put(TiC.EVENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE, this);
    resultCallback.callAsync(event);
}
```

And also see the Appcelerator JS calling the method in the module:

```
square.runPayment(2, 'Testing123', function(e) {
    label1.text = 'Payment Successful!';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For those that come upon this question. The answer can be found in the module here:
https://github.com/hidef/Appcelerator-Square-Module (see the LaunchSquare.java class)

Basically, I used an Activity object that I created to receive the Square API's onResult update. I then was able to pass that back cleanly to the module class and hand it back via callback to the calling application.

Comment: can you explain more? I have a similar issue, I have an .aar android module I created that all has the onActivityResult function which is not being called

I assume its because the module is not the main activity so I need to intercept this function from my Alloy app